# Xamarin.Forms (UWP) - How Can I Get a WebView's DOM as an HTML String?

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

In a Xamarin.Forms (UWP) project, I have a `WebView` control whose `Source` is created with an HTML string, like this:

```
var webview = new Xamarin.Forms.WebView
{
    Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = "<html>....</html>"
    }
};
```

The HTML contains JavaScript that dynamically generates HTML inside the `<body>`. This renders perfectly on the screen. That means the WebView understands the DOM that is being created with the JavaScript. Great.

But now I need to parse through some of the generated HTML, but all I can seem to access is the original HTML string that I passed in as the Source, and not the final generated DOM.

**Is there a way to convert the DOM generated by the JavaScript and understood by the WebView into a string so that I can parse (using a library like HTML Agility Pack or AngleSharp) and pull out some segments of the HTML? This can be in Xamarin.Forms or UWP (the platform I'm targeting).**

**NOTE:** In full disclosure (in case it helps, and to avoid accusations of this being an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), I am ultimately trying to solve the problem of printing a WebView with multiple pages on UWP - research on this has been met with very sparse information. I have a solution that works for HTML that is not dynamically generated with JavaScript - basically I'm pulling out parts of the HTML that represent printable pages, and I'm adding those as separate pages for print and print preview. But as mentioned earlier, I can't seem to parse through dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to use the `Eval` method built into Xamarin.Forms, but then I found out this is method does not return anything so it is suitable only for app-to-webview communication.

So far the easiest way to implement this is using a custom version of the `WebView` control:

```cs
public class ExtendedWebView : WebView
{
    public delegate Task<string> GetHtmlRequestedHandler();

    public event GetHtmlRequestedHandler GetHtmlRequested;


    public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        var handler = GetHtmlRequested;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            return await handler.Invoke();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now in UWP platform project create a custom renderer:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedWebView), typeof(ExtendedWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App.UWP
{
    public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                var ew = (e.OldElement as ExtendedWebView);
                ew.GetHtmlRequested -= Ew_GetHtmlRequested;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var ew = (e.NewElement as ExtendedWebView);
                ew.GetHtmlRequested += Ew_GetHtmlRequested;
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> Ew_GetHtmlRequested()
        {
            return await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is that we are calling the JavaScript `eval` function that will return the HTML itself from the web view.

You just need to replace the `WebView` in XAML with our `ExtendedWebView` and call its `GetHtmlAsync` method whenever needed.

The only thing I dislike about this solution is that the `event` has `Task<string>` return type, which is weird. Actually already having a return type on event is unusual. A better solution would be to put a property in custom `EventArgs` that the native control would set with result of the operation, but because the `InvokeScriptAsync` method is asynchronous (and the non-asynchronous `InvokeScript` method is obsolete and should no longer be used) we would have to implement a custom `Task` that would complete when the property is set. Such approach is utilized in UWP with some events, they are using a "deferral" which says the caller that the event will finish only after some asynchronous operation finishes. I will try to look for some authoritative answer on how calling a native asynchronous operation should be implemented in case of custom views :-) .

Comment: Great idea! But question - when `Ew_GetHtmlRequested` is invoked in the platform code, can we be sure that the DOM content has completely loaded? There is a `Control.DOMContentLoaded` event - should we incorporate that somehow?